# How to implement pixel-wise classification for scene labeling in TensorFlow?

Tags: computer-vision, classification, tensorflow, scene, labeling

I am working on a deep learning model using **Google's TensorFlow**. The model should be used to **segment and label scenes**.

1. I am using the **SiftFlow dataset** which has *33 semantic
   classes* and *images with 256x256 pixels*.
2. As a result, at my final layer using convolution and deconvolution I arrive at the following tensor(array) *[256, 256, 33]*.
3. Next I would like to
   apply *Softmax* and compare the results to a semantic label of size
   *[256, 256]*.

**Questions:**
Should I apply mean averaging or argmax to my final layer so its shape becomes *[256,256,1]* and then loop through each pixel and classify as if I were classying *256x256* instances? If the answer is yes, how, if not, what other options?

Answer (score 12):

To apply softmax and use a **cross entropy loss**, you have to keep **intact** the final output of your network of size *batch_size x 256 x 256 x 33*. Therefore you **cannot use** mean averaging or argmax because it would destroy the output probabilities of your network.

You have to loop through all the *batch_size x 256 x 256* pixels and apply a cross entropy loss to your prediction for this pixel. This is easy with the built-in function `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, labels)`.

Some warnings [from the doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/nn.html#sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits) before applying the code below:

- WARNING: This op expects **unscaled logits**, since it performs a softmax on logits internally for efficiency. Do not call this op with the output of softmax, as it will produce incorrect results.
- logits and must have the shape [batch_size, num_classes] and the dtype (either float32 or float64).
- labels must have the shape [batch_size] and the dtype int64.

The trick is to use `batch_size * 256 * 256` as the batch size required by the function. We will reshape `logits` and `labels` to this format.
Here is the code I use:

```py
inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, 256, 256, 3])  # input images
logits = inference(inputs)  # your outputs of shape [batch_size, 256, 256, 33] (no final softmax !!)
labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, 256, 256])  # your labels of shape [batch_size, 256, 256] and type int64

reshaped_logits = tf.reshape(logits, [-1, 33])  # shape [batch_size*256*256, 33]
reshaped_labels = tf.reshape(labels, [-1])  # shape [batch_size*256*256]
loss = sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(reshaped_logits, reshaped_labels)
```

You can then apply your optimizer on that loss.

---

#### Update: v0.10

The [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/nn.html#sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits) of `tf.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` shows that it now accepts any shape for `logits`, so there is no need to reshape the tensors (thanks @chillinger):

```py
inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, 256, 256, 3])  # input images
logits = inference(inputs)  # your outputs of shape [batch_size, 256, 256, 33] (no final softmax !!)
labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, 256, 256])  # your labels of shape [batch_size, 256, 256] and type int64

loss = sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, labels)
```

Comment: How do you then feed y data into labels if it has shape `(?,)` ?

Comment: I updated the answer to make it clear where you feed your data. You feed `labels` (of shape `[batch_size, 256, 256]`) with your y data, and then reshape it to `(?,)`

Comment: There's actually no need for reshaping/flattening the `logits` and `labels`. `tf.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` can handle arbitrary shapes as long as the `logits` have an extra `dim`.

Comment: You are right, since version 0.10 you don't need to reshape I will update the answer