# Tensorflow TypeError

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm trying to train a NN using the code in here https://github.com/RobRomijnders/LSTM_tsc.

After lots of changes to fit my data i get this error:

TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type

I have search for the answer as i did with previous errors i found but although i get here:
[Tensorflow TypeError on session.run arguments/output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38306330/tensorflow-typeerror-on-session-run-arguments-output)

i think that my code is not incurring in that (at least i cannot find it)

```
import numpy as np
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL']='3'
import tensorflow as tf
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
sys.path.append('E:\\Descargas\\recommendersystems\\train')
from tsc_model import Model,sample_batch,load_data,check_test


config = {}                             #Put all configuration information into the dict
config['num_layers'] = 3                #number of layers of stacked RNN's
config['hidden_size'] = 120              #memory cells in a layer
config['max_grad_norm'] = 5             #maximum gradient norm during training
config['batch_size'] = batch_size = 30  
config['learning_rate'] = .005
config['num_classes'] = 2

max_iterations = 3000
dropout = 0.8
ratio = np.array([0.8,0.9]) #Ratios where to split the training and validation set


direc = 'E:\\Descargas\\recommendersystems\\ets_challenge\\train\\train3.csv'
X_train,X_val,X_test,y_train,y_val,y_test = load_data(direc,ratio)
N,sl = X_train.shape
config['sl'] = sl = X_train.shape[1]
config['num_classes'] = num_classes = len(np.unique(y_train))

# Collect the costs in a numpy fashion
epochs = np.floor(batch_size*max_iterations / N)
print('Train %.0f samples in approximately %d epochs' %(N,epochs))
perf_collect = np.zeros((4,int(np.floor(max_iterations /100))))

#Instantiate a model
model = Model(config)




sess = tf.Session() #Depending on your use, do not forget to close the session
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("/home/rob/Dropbox/ml_projects/LSTM/log_tb", sess.graph)  #writer for Tensorboard
sess.run(model.init_op)

step = 0
cost_train_ma = -np.log(1/float(num_classes)+1e-9)  #Moving average training cost
acc_train_ma = 0.0
try:
  for i in range(max_iterations):
    X_batch, y_batch = sample_batch(X_train,y_train,batch_size)

    #Next line does the actual training
    cost_train, acc_train,_ = sess.run([model.cost,model.accuracy, model.train_op],feed_dict = {model.input: X_batch,model.labels: y_batch,model.keep_prob:dropout})
    cost_train_ma = cost_train_ma*0.99 + cost_train*0.01
    acc_train_ma = acc_train_ma*0.99 + acc_train*0.01
    if i%100 == 0:
      #Evaluate training performance
      perf_collect[0,step] = cost_train
      perf_collect[1,step] = acc_train

      #Evaluate validation performance
      X_batch, y_batch = sample_batch(X_val,y_val,batch_size)
      cost_val, summ,acc_val = sess.run([model.cost,model.merged,model.accuracy],feed_dict = {model.input: X_batch, model.labels: y_batch, model.keep_prob:1.0})
      perf_collect[1,step] = cost_val
      perf_collect[2,step] = acc_val
      print('At %5.0f/%5.0f: COST %5.3f/%5.3f(%5.3f) -- Acc %5.3f/%5.3f(%5.3f)' %(i,max_iterations,cost_train,cost_val,cost_train_ma,acc_train,acc_val,acc_train_ma))

      #Write information to TensorBoard
      writer.add_summary(summ, i)
      writer.flush()

      step +=1
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  #Pressing ctrl-c will end training. This try-except ensures we still plot the performance
  pass

acc_test,cost_test = check_test(model,sess,X_test,y_test)
epoch = float(i)*batch_size/N
print('After training %.1f epochs, test accuracy is %5.3f and test cost is %5.3f'%(epoch,acc_test,cost_test))


plt.plot(perf_collect[0],label='Train')
plt.plot(perf_collect[1],label = 'Valid')
plt.plot(perf_collect[2],label = 'Valid accuracy')
plt.axis([0, step, 0, np.max(perf_collect)])
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

And this is the error trace

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-200bd46aa85d> in <module>()
     64       #Evaluate validation performance
     65       X_batch, y_batch = sample_batch(X_val,y_val,batch_size)
---> 66       cost_val, summ,acc_val = sess.run([model.cost,model.merged,model.accuracy],feed_dict = {model.input: X_batch, model.labels: y_batch, model.keep_prob:1.0})
     67       perf_collect[1,step] = cost_val
     68       perf_collect[2,step] = acc_val

\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    765     try:
    766       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 767                          run_metadata_ptr)
    768       if run_metadata:
    769         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    950 
    951     # Create a fetch handler to take care of the structure of fetches.
--> 952     fetch_handler = _FetchHandler(self._graph, fetches, feed_dict_string)
    953 
    954     # Run request and get response.

\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in __init__(self, graph, fetches, feeds)
    406     """
    407     with graph.as_default():
--> 408       self._fetch_mapper = _FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetches)
    409     self._fetches = []
    410     self._targets = []

\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in for_fetch(fetch)
    228     elif isinstance(fetch, (list, tuple)):
    229       # NOTE(touts): This is also the code path for namedtuples.
--> 230       return _ListFetchMapper(fetch)
    231     elif isinstance(fetch, dict):
    232       return _DictFetchMapper(fetch)

\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in __init__(self, fetches)
    335     """
    336     self._fetch_type = type(fetches)
--> 337     self._mappers = [_FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetch) for fetch in fetches]
    338     self._unique_fetches, self._value_indices = _uniquify_fetches(self._mappers)
    339 

\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    335     """
    336     self._fetch_type = type(fetches)
--> 337     self._mappers = [_FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetch) for fetch in fetches]
    338     self._unique_fetches, self._value_indices = _uniquify_fetches(self._mappers)
    339 

\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in for_fetch(fetch)
    225     if fetch is None:
    226       raise TypeError('Fetch argument %r has invalid type %r' %
--> 227                       (fetch, type(fetch)))
    228     elif isinstance(fetch, (list, tuple)):
    229       # NOTE(touts): This is also the code path for namedtuples.

TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type <class 'NoneType'>
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it appears that one of `model.cost`, `model.merged`, or `model.accuracy` is `None`. Looking at the [original source](https://github.com/RobRomijnders/LSTM_tsc/blob/087c5804b10f8d644773559e082bc89835542bf8/tsc_model.py), all of these attributes of a `Model` object seem to be assigned in `Model.__init__()`: `self.cost` is assigned [here](https://github.com/RobRomijnders/LSTM_tsc/blob/087c5804b10f8d644773559e082bc89835542bf8/tsc_model.py#L108), `self.merged` is assigned [here](https://github.com/RobRomijnders/LSTM_tsc/blob/087c5804b10f8d644773559e082bc89835542bf8/tsc_model.py#L135), and `self.accuracy` is assigned [here](https://github.com/RobRomijnders/LSTM_tsc/blob/087c5804b10f8d644773559e082bc89835542bf8/tsc_model.py#L111).

It is most likely that one of your changes to the code (to make it fit your data) has changed the control flow in that constructor so that one of these assignments no longer happens. I'd recommend first identifying which of the attributes is `None`, then tracing through `Model.__init__()` to discover why it is not being set.