# Variable clash inTensorFlow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

So I have a problem same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38306330/typeerror-fetch-argument-has-invalid-type-float32-must-be-a-string-or-tensor) question. Except I cannot find out which name is clashing. Can you please point out where exactly the variable name clash is occurring, I have tried a lot to no avail. Or you can suggest some methods to find out the point of error. Here is my TensorFlow code:

```html
def convolutionForwardPropagation(features, labels, mode, params):
    img = features['x']
    
    c1 = tf.layers.conv2d(img, filters = 32, kernel_size = [1,3], padding = 'VALID', activation = tf.nn.relu, kernel_regularizer = tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(20.0))
    c2 = tf.layers.conv2d(c1, filters = 64, kernel_size = [1,3], padding = 'VALID', activation = tf.nn.relu, kernel_regularizer = tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(20.0))
    
    c3 = tf.layers.conv2d(c2, filters = 64, kernel_size = [1,3], padding = 'VALID', activation = tf.nn.relu, kernel_regularizer = tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(20.0))
    c4 = tf.layers.conv2d(c3, filters = 64, kernel_size = [1,3], padding = 'VALID', activation = tf.nn.relu, kernel_regularizer = tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(20.0))
        
    c5 = tf.layers.conv2d(c4, filters = 128, kernel_size = [1,3], padding = 'VALID', activation = tf.nn.relu, kernel_regularizer = tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(20.0))
    
    shape1 = c5.get_shape().as_list()
    fr = tf.reshape(c5, shape = (-1, shape1[3] * shape1[2]))
    
    fc1 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(fr, 20, activation_fn = tf.nn.relu, weights_regularizer = tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(500.0))
    fc2 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(fc1, 2, activation_fn = tf.nn.sigmoid, weights_regularizer = tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(500.0))

    entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits = fc2, labels = labels, name = 'cross_entropy')
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(entropy, name = 'loss')

    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(params)

    hypothesis = tf.nn.softmax(fc2)
    y_pred_class = tf.argmax(hypothesis, axis = 1)
    sparseLabels = tf.argmax(labels, axis = 1)
    
    
    if(mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT):
        spec = tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode = mode, predictions = y_pred_class)
        return spec
        
    elif(mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN):
        train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss = loss)
        metrics = {'accuracy':tf.metrics.accuracy(labels = sparseLabels, predictions = y_pred_class)}
        spec = tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode = mode, predictions = y_pred_class, loss = loss, train_op = train_op, eval_metric_ops = metrics)
        return spec
    
    elif(mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL):
        metrics = {'accuracy':tf.metrics.accuracy(labels = sparseLabels, predictions = y_pred_class)}
        spec = tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode = mode, predictions = y_pred_class, loss = loss, eval_metric_ops = metrics)
        return spec



train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(x = {'x':testDataset}, y = labelsTest, batch_size = 350, num_epochs = 20, shuffle = False)
eval_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(x = {'x':CVDataset}, y = labelsCV, batch_size = 200, num_epochs = 1, shuffle = False)
model = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn = convolutionForwardPropagation, params = learning_rate, model_dir = './checpoints/CNN')
k = model.train(input_fn = train_input_fn, steps = 1)

writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./graphs/logreg', tf.get_default_graph())
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run([train_input_fn, eval_input_fn])
    sess.run([model, k])
writer.close()
```

And here is my error message:

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-36-08caa0f29863>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/home/abhigyan/Programming_Projects/Python_Projects/tensorflow_env/Programs/tfCNN3.py', wdir='/home/abhigyan/Programming_Projects/Python_Projects/tensorflow_env/Programs')

  File "/home/abhigyan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/home/abhigyan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/home/abhigyan/Programming_Projects/Python_Projects/tensorflow_env/Programs/tfCNN3.py", line 222, in <module>
    sess.run([train_input_fn, eval_input_fn])

  File "/home/abhigyan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 900, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)

  File "/home/abhigyan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1120, in _run
    self._graph, fetches, feed_dict_tensor, feed_handles=feed_handles)

  File "/home/abhigyan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 427, in __init__
    self._fetch_mapper = _FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetches)

  File "/home/abhigyan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 245, in for_fetch
    return _ListFetchMapper(fetch)

  File "/home/abhigyan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 352, in __init__
    self._mappers = [_FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetch) for fetch in fetches]

  File "/home/abhigyan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 352, in <listcomp>
    self._mappers = [_FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetch) for fetch in fetches]

  File "/home/abhigyan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 253, in for_fetch
    return _ElementFetchMapper(fetches, contraction_fn)

  File "/home/abhigyan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 286, in __init__
    (fetch, type(fetch), str(e)))

TypeError: Fetch argument <function numpy_input_fn.<locals>.input_fn at 0x7f52300b2510> has invalid type <class 'function'>, must be a string or Tensor. (Can not convert a function into a Tensor or Operation.)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the error because the method `sess.run()` is trying to execute a Tensor, whereas your input to the method `[train_input_fn, eval_input_fn]` are functions.

However, you do not need `tf.Session()` when working with the Estimator API. To train your model:

#### 1). First, execute the model

```
model = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn = convolutionForwardPropagation, 
                          params = learning_rate, model_dir = './checpoints/CNN')
```

#### 2). Second, run the train and validation inputs

```
train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(x = {'x':testDataset},
                  y = labelsTest, batch_size = 350, num_epochs = 20,
                  shuffle = False)
eval_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(x = {'x':CVDataset},
                 y = labelsCV, batch_size = 200, num_epochs = 1,
                 shuffle = False)
```

#### 3). Then run the training and validation method

Now you can do something like this:

```
for epoch in range(20):
        model.train(input_fn = train_input_fn, steps = None)
        training_score = model.evaluate(input_fn=train_input_fn)
        validation_score = model.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn)
```

Comment: Hmmm...I figured it out eventually,  was wondering though why we did not require sess

Comment: Because the `Estimator` class handles the execution of the computational Graph internally, so you do not need to handle Graph execution manually using `Sessions`.