# Using median frequency balancing with sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, image-segmentation

I'm currently working on using tensorflow to adress a multi-class segmentation problem on a [SegNet Architecture](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.00561v2.pdf)

My classes are heavily unbalanced and thus I need to integrate the [median frequency balancing](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.4734v4.pdf) (using weights on classes on loss calculation). I use the following tip (based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35317029/how-to-implement-pixel-wise-classification-for-scene-labeling-in-tensorflow)) to apply Softmax. I need help to extend it in order to add the weights, I'm not sure how to do it. Current implementation:

```
reshaped_logits = tf.reshape(logits, [-1, nClass])
reshaped_labels = tf.reshape(labels, [-1])
loss = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(reshaped_logits, reshaped_labels)
```

My idea would be:

1. To split the logits tensor in nClass tensor,
2. Apply the softmax on each independently,
3. Weight them with median frequency balancing
4. Finally, summing the weighted losses.

Would that be the right approach?

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the code to do that [here](https://github.com/MarvinTeichmann/KittiSeg/blob/master/decoder/kitti_multiloss.py#L96-L103)

```
def _compute_cross_entropy_mean(class_weights, labels, softmax):
    cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(labels * tf.log(softmax), class_weights),
                                   reduction_indices=[1])

    cross_entropy_mean = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy,
                                        name='xentropy_mean')
    return cross_entropy_mean
```

where `head` is your class weighing matrix.